# Localized OS X app refusing to run in the Base English localization

Tags: xcode, macos, localization, osx-mountain-lion

I have a localized OS X app.
There are several languages supported, the Base localization is English:

[image: Xcode screenshot]

When testing on Mountain Lion, the app behaves strangely.
It refuses to run in English, as if the localization was missing. (On modern OS X versions it works just fine.)

What could be the problem?
I tried duplicating the `Base.lproj` folder from the app bundle as `en.lproj` and the problem disappeared.
 Is this a problem with Base Internationalization support in older OS X versions?

Comment: Is anything written to the console log when you attempt to launch it?

Comment: Nope, nothing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I would love to have a better solution, in the end I have added a “run script” build phase that just copies `Base.lproj` to `en.lproj` in the app bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently - my macOS app running on 10.8 instead of showing English locale was presenting the first foreign language in my bundle.

And I found solution - it turns out that it is because lack of English version of Localizable.strings file. The one that I had was marked as 'Base'. When I unchecked 'Base' for Localizable.strings (leaving all the xibs intact) and confirmed that it is 'English' all the dialogs switched to English in runtime as well.

I've seen this in 10.8 only - there is no such issue in 10.10 or never systems (I don't know about 10.9).